# Why is my javascript match returning null?

Tags: javascript, regex

Using the following text as my msg variable:

```
/private UserName:some message without leading whitespace
/private UserName: some message with leading whitespace
```

And the following javascript to parse it:

```
if(msg.indexOf('/private') == 0){
    msg = msg.substring(8,msg.length);
    var parts = msg.match(/\s+(.+?)\:\s*(.+?)/);

    alert("Name: " + parts[0]);
    alert("Message: " + parts[1]);
}
```

I would expect index 0 to contain **UserName** 
and index 1 to contain **some message with ...**

Anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tweak your regex a little bit:

```
/^\/private\s+(.*?):\s*(.*?)$/
```

And simplify your code:

```
var regex = /^\/private\s+(.*?):\s*(.*?)$/;
var parts = regex.exec(msg);

if (parts){
    alert("Name: " + parts[1]);
    alert("Message: " + parts[2]);
}
```

`parts[0]` is the entire matched string. You want `parts[1]` and `parts[2]`.

Comment: that was it...I'm so used to working with PERL and PHP I forgot about that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var msg = '/private UserName:some message without leading whitespace \
/private UserName: some message with leading whitespace';

if (msg.indexOf('/private') == 0) {
   msg = msg.substring(8,msg.length);
   var parts = msg.match(/\s+(.+?)\:\s*(.+?)/);

   console.log("Name: " + parts[0]);
   console.log("Message: " + parts[1]);
}
```

Prints out

```
  Name:  UserName:s
  Message: UserName
```

I would debug the value of your `msg` and `parts` variables. Also, check your regex on a site like http://regexpal.com/. It looks like your regex may be matching too much. Do you want it to end with the colon? If so, try something more like this

```
\s+(\S+?)\:
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to split and trim :)

something like :

```
parts = msg.split(" ",1)[1].split(":",1);

alert("Name: " + parts[0]);
alert("Message: " + $trim(parts[1]));
```

[trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) is a jquery function but you could do it with regex :)